# jquery simple compute function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I want to compute and display a simple jquery function here but its not showing up.

This is the jQuery code:

```
function compute() {
      var a = $('#a').val();
      var b = $('#pln').val();
      var c = $('#c').val();
      var d = a*b;
      var total = d+c;
      $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
    }
$('#a, #b, #c, #d').change(compute);
```

And this is the form code where I want to implement it and show the calculated value.

```
        <div>
          <label style="margin-top: 25px;">Timer duration</label>
          <input type="radio" id="mc a" name="optionsRadios" value="<?php echo $at_fetch['at_mc']; ?>" style="margin-left: -170px; margin-top: 3px;">
          <font style='margin-left: -170px; font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Arial;'><?php echo $at_fetch['at_mc']; ?> secs (Micro Ads)</font><br />
          <input type="radio" id="mn a" name="optionsRadios" value="<?php echo $at_fetch['at_mn']; ?>" style="margin-left: -170px; margin-top: 3px;">
          <font style='margin-left: -170px; font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Arial;'><?php echo $at_fetch['at_mn']; ?> secs (Mini Ads)</font><br />
          <input type="radio" id="sd a" name="optionsRadios" value="<?php echo $at_fetch['at_sd']; ?>" style="margin-left: 62px; margin-top: 3px;">
          <font style='margin-left: -170px; font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Arial;'><?php echo $at_fetch['at_sd']; ?> secs (Standard Ads)</font><br />
          <input type="radio" id="fd a" name="optionsRadios" value="<?php echo $at_fetch['at_fd']; ?>" style="margin-left: 62px; margin-top: 3px;">
          <font style='margin-left: -170px; font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode",Arial;'><?php echo $at_fetch['at_fd']; ?> secs (Fixed Ads)</font><br />
        </div>

        <div style="margin-top: -60px;">
          <label>Choose plan</label>
          <select name="" id="pln" class="select-box" style="margin-top: -40px;"  />
          <option value="0">Choose clicks</option>
          <?php while($ac_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($qur_ac)){ ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $ac_fetch['adclk_clicks']; ?>"><?php echo $ac_fetch['adclk_clicks']; ?> clicks</option>
          <?php } ?>
          </select>
        </div>


        <div>
          <label>Fees</label>
          $<?php echo $paf_fetch['paf_fees']; ?>
          <input type="hidden" id="c" value="<?php echo $paf_fetch['paf_fees']; ?>" />
        </div>


        <div>
          <label>Total
          <input type="text" id="total" value="" disabled>
        </div></label>
        <br /><br />
```

I want this jquery to compute the values and display in the `<input type="text" id="total" value="" disabled>`. But its not showing. Please help me up with this.

Comment: `div` does not have property `value`. You should try `.html()` or `.text()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `$('#total').html(total.toFixed(2));`

Comment: Are you sure that `total.toFixed(2)` is returning something?

Comment: This will work when just want to simply change a text or  when I want to implement any html value.... How can this function help me in computing and displaying a value? Please revise your answer..

Comment: The `#total` is a `div` tag, therefore the isn't a `$.val()` function.

Comment: then what if I use <input type="text" id="total" value="" disabled>.... Now help me if I use this....

Comment: I think you mislead the selector, you can't have two ID's in an element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#total').val("");
    $('input[name="optionsRadios"], #pln').change(function () {            
        var a = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        var b = parseInt($('#pln').val(), 10);
        var c = parseInt($('#c').val(), 10);
        var d = a * b;
        var total = d + c;
        $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

html

```
          <label style="margin-top: 25px;">Timer duration</label>
      <br />

      <table>
<tr>
    <td> <input type="radio" id="mc_a" name="optionsRadios" value="1">   </td>
    <td>  secs (Micro Ads)</td>
</tr>

          <tr>
              <td>  <input type="radio" id="mn a" name="optionsRadios" value="2" ></td>
              <td>secs (Mini Ads)</td>
          </tr>
                <tr>
              <td><input type="radio" id="sd a" name="optionsRadios" value="3" ></td>
              <td> secs (Standard Ads)</td>
          </tr>
  <tr>
              <td> <input type="radio" id="fd a" name="optionsRadios" value="4" ></td>
              <td> secs (Fixed Ads)</td>
          </tr>
      </table>






          <label>Choose plan</label>
          <select name="" id="pln" class="select-box"  />
          <option value="0">Choose clicks</option>

          <option value="10">10</option>

          <option value="20">20</option>

          <option value="30">40</option>

          <option value="50">50</option>

          </select>



        <div>
          <label>Fees</label>

          <input type="text" id="c" value="22" />
        </div>


        <div>
          <label>Total
          <input type="text" id="total" value="" disabled>
        </div></label>
        <br /><br />
```

Have added some dummy values to check your function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
   var total = a+b;                  
   $('#total :input').attr('value',total);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to get value from input `radio` element by `id`. 
The identifiers of your `radio` elements are not consists with those which are presented within `compute()` function. Besides, you should get `radio` element's value by checking `checked` state. 
Change your code as shown below:

```
function compute() {
      var a = $("input[name='optionsRadios']:checked").val(),
          b = $('#pln').val(),
          c = $('#c').val(),
          d = a*b,
          total = d+c;
      $('#total').val(total.toFixed(2));
    }
$('input[name='optionsRadios'], #c, #pln').change(compute);
```